Is there a way to disable winapi global keyboard hook?
Is there any way to disable the global low-level keyboard hooking mechanism?  I'm thinking of the case where my app accepts a password: it would be nice to stop all other apps listening to the keyboard at that point.
I know one can use the on-screen keyboard osk.exe to mitigate, but it would be nice to stop keyloggers, etc.

Attackers don't need a global keyboard hook to steal your passwords. They can just inject code into your process and extract the passwords that way.

I'm pretty sure that an on-screen keyboard will not bypass a low-level keyboard hook. Have you verified this?

@PhilCoder: related: In which order do the hooks set by SetWindowsHookEx() receive messages?.  You can't disable hooks, but the most recent hook installed is called first, so you could try installing your own hook right before you receive the input, and then have your hook prevent events from being passed down the chain.  But, it is not guaranteed that an attacker would not simply reinstall their hook after yours.

Code injection?  Not something I had considered.  Does an attacker need admin privileges to do that?

The attacker just needs to run at the same or higher privilege as your app.

Thanks all, I'm going to do some reading on the windows security model.  My bad, I lost touch with windows internals after win 3.x :)

FYI I did some tests.  My keyboard hook running as ordinary user doesnt catch keystrokes if my app (or any app) runs as administrator.

To summarize, disabling the global low-level keyboard hooking mechanism is not a proper way for protection.
As @RaymondChen said,

Attackers don't need a global keyboard hook to steal your passwords.
They can just inject code into your process and extract the passwords
that way.

You should also have a look at this document, Enable virtualization-based protection of code integrity.
